# Is there a way to go back to column 1 in less?

Tags: less

At times, my software (generally while testing) outputs very long lines, so I use the -S command line option which means I see one line instead of possibly many screens of data.

Once in a while, I like to verify that data which means I scroll right through the very long (wide) line.

Once I'm done, I'd like to be able to come back to column 1 with a key. I tried 0 and 1 and ^ (i.e. like in vim) but it doesn't look like that works. I'm thinking that there may not be a way even though you'd think that's an important feature...

Comment: The left arrow key?

Comment: If you are 10 or even 20 screens to the right, that's a lot of left arrows...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Press `h` to show the help, which says:

```
ESC-)  RightArrow *  Right one half screen width (or N positions).
ESC-(  LeftArrow  *  Left  one half screen width (or N positions).
ESC-}  ^RightArrow   Right to last column displayed.
ESC-{  ^LeftArrow    Left  to first column.
```

Or press and hold the left arrow key.

Comment: I guess I have a version that's too old (Ubuntu 16.04, Less 481)... because the `ESC-{` and I suppose the `^LeftArray` means `Ctrl-LeftArray`, correct? Neither works on my machine. However, the `ESC-(` works. Press and hold works okay for a few screens, when you have many, it's not that great. Oh well... I'll have to switch to my new computer soon and see whether it works on that one.

Comment: @AlexisWilke you could try something like `10000 Esc (` (type 10000 or some arbitrarily large number before `Esc-(`).

Comment: Ah! Now that works. Cool! Thank you.